# Why won't my links trigger jQuery.click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I'm dabbling in some jQuery today, and I come across an issue. I have a page that has a number of links in the following format:

```
<a class="a_link" id="a_id<#>" href="#">Click me</a>
```

Where `<#>` is a number generated in a for loop in the PHP that runs the page. At the top of the page, I have a script tag linking to the Google CDN for jQuery 1.7.2 minimized, and a div with id of "form_map". After all the links have been displayed, I have the following script:

```
<script type="text/css">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.a_link').click(function(){
            var c_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var task = 'read';
            var ajax_url = 'engine.php';
            alert('link pressed for id: '+c_id);
            $.get({
                url: ajax_url, 
                data: { 'task':task, 'c_id':c_id }, 
                success: function(res){ $('#form_map').val(res); } 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Disregarding all that wonky Ajax calls (which also do not seem to work correctly), when I click a link nothing happens. It doesn't even run the script. I tested this by setting a breakpoint and adding the alert. Nothing seems to even trigger this.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your script type is listed as "text/css"...it should be "text/javascript".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

instead of:

```
<script type="text/css">
```

also use:

```
$('#form_map').html(res);
```

instead of

```
$('#form_map').val(res);
```

Comment: Or not even that... the `type` attribute on a `<script>` block containing Javascript is completely optional if you're using the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), which hopefully you are if this is a new project.

Comment: Changing the type to text/javascript gets the script to function at least. I even have the doctype as <!doctype html> so it should render in firefox and chrome as html 5. I don't know why my get function is not posting the message from my ajax script, but i will figure that part out eventually.

Comment: The AJAX call might not be working because `$.get()` takes `url`, `data`, etc as normal arguments, not as an object. Try `$.get(ajax_url, {'task':task, 'c_id':c_id}, ...)`, or use `$.ajax()` which *does* take an object.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to fix the opening  tag

```
<script type="text/css">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to return false at the end of the function you pass into .click().

```
$('.a_link').click(function() {
  // Your AJAX stuff here.
  return false;
});
```

Returning false stops the link from continuing to work as normal.